# Is "youth" gender-neutral when countable?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, gender-neutral, countable-nouns

Matt Errey at the "English Club" website [suggests otherwise](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Nouns_that_are_Count_and_Noncount/youth_3033.htm).

I can easily choose "young people" over "youth," but doing so might suggest I am doing it to increase word count.

Comment: _Youth_ as a count noun referring to a young (male) person is somewhat pejorative and derogatory, so if you’re writing some kind of essay/article/academic text, I would suggest not using it at all. _Young people_ is the natural phrasing, and no one would ever dream of associating its usage with an attempt to increase word count.

Comment: If "youth" refers to young males specifically, I wonder is there an equivalent for young females?

Comment: Youngsters also is gender neutral.  MW: Full Definition of youngster
1
a :  a young person :  youth
b :  child
2
:  a young animal or plant especially of a domesticated or cultivated breed or type

Comment: @N.Owad A youth or youths does not refer specifically to males it just implies it. It is usually used to refer to bored teenagers outside shops or on street corners up to mischief (who happen to be mostly male).

Comment: This following version from the movie "My Cousin Vinny" (1992) refers to two "youths," who are both male. The actor pronounces the plural (countable) as "yutes."  Written dialogue: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104952/quotes?item=qt0404568 and video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVjbf-dHjW0.

Comment: 'Word count' implies 'governing body' implies 'style guide'.

Comment: @KDog At least in British English, "youngsters" carries very different connotations to "youths". "Youngsters" could easily mean children of primary school age, whereas "youths" almost certainly does not.

Answer (score 16):

[Oxford Dictionary of English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/youth) defines the countable noun *youth* as 'a young man'; [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/youth) defines it as 'a young person, especially a young man or boy'; [Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/youth) defines it as 'a young person, especially a young male between adolescence and maturity'; [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=youth) defines it as 'a young person, especially a young male in late adolescence'.

This probably happened because the countable noun *youth* was used mostly to refer to males at the time the lexicographers composed the definitions. Indeed, you can use it to refer to both males and females, given that three of the four definitions cited here allow for it, using only the qualifier *especially* and not *exclusively*.

Comment: This comparison of dictionary definitions is certainly beyond a general reference answer. It is also instructive that questions or answers beginning 'The dictionary says ...' should be treated very warily, if not dismissively. // Have you a reference to what I usually refer to as 'ODO' is actually named [The] 'Oxford Dictionary of English' by the editors? All I can find is 'Oxford Dictionaries' for 'not the OED'; it seems an unnecessarily ambiguous choice of title (polysemy-with-hypernymy).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Your comment prompted me to do some research. Both the OED and Oxford Dictionaries Online are published by the [Oxford University Press](http://global.oup.com/?cc=gb). They are therefore clearly *related*, but I would not say they are the same thing. in fact, they have separate links on the OUP website (hover over "Dictionaries" to see).

Comment: Here's a [courtroom video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=K6qGwmXZtsE) showing the word being used FYI. Bonus regional accent included.

Comment: @AndyT We often have to correct 'OED says ...'-type statements on ELU. The dictionary accessed say [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/research) is certainly not OED; all I am inquiring about is what OUP want us to call it.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not disputing anything you've said but, from a practical standpoint, I would never have thought "youths" had a male-dominated meaning. My usage (and that of those around me) does not hold this connotation.

Answer (score 9):

In sociology/social work, *youth* is a gender-neutral term referring to people in their teenage years (especially the late teenage years) and their early twenties. It is especially common in the phrases *at-risk youth* and *homeless youth*.

I spent some time writing about the child welfare system in a state where people were eligible for services up to age 21. I was encouraged to use *children and youth* as the collective term for the people served by this system. This frequently involved gender-neutral count usage (e.g., "about 9,000 children and youth are in out-of-home care").

Here are some examples of gender-neutral count usage from around the Internet, mostly with additional modifiers "at-risk" or "homeless" because they are easier to search for:

- Many examples, e.g., ["a number of youth identified the theme..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=MGAAeaqLcvgC&pg=PA458&lpg=PA458&dq=%22three+youth+were%22&source=bl&ots=3o4AigqHtw&sig=40ySP4NytJnSmlJRd6swWGL93e4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig-qW3r-zPAhVP_WMKHR1zDn0Q6AEIODAH#v=onepage&q=%22three%20youth%20were%22&f=false) (PhD dissertation)
- Many examples, e.g., ["Only two youth I interviewed..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=s5vdvTFn1LoC&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=%22two+youth+were%22&source=bl&ots=27RTqCmlSX&sig=CWMOvUReH5euzJ95QhzBpG9BlYc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYlZDHr-zPAhUBwWMKHVDfADUQ6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=%22two%20youth%20were%22&f=false) (book)
- ["Five youth were living in foster care..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=soLWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22five+youth+were%22&source=bl&ots=wqgNbnlOgJ&sig=fK_CnH5626Vq3XhxclbQfp5SfHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv-NDTr-zPAhUD52MKHXbrBr8Q6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22five%20youth%20were%22&f=false) (book)
- ["twenty-three sponsored youth participated in a life-changing experience..."](http://www.critterbarn.org/site/c.ihKMIWPDIqE/b.4284829/k.4642/Critter_Camp_for_AtRisk_Youth.htm) (organization website)
- ["One-in-three 'at-risk' youth in school..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=UeI-fq5pCyYC&lpg=PA225&ots=SSDy1m9xRZ&dq=%22three%20at-risk%20youth%22&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q=%22three%20at-risk%20youth%22&f=false) (book)
- ["Three at-risk youth have been awarded scholarships"](http://www.newsradioklbj.com/blogs/todd-jeffries-closer-look/council-risk-youth-bully-bullied-and-hte-bystander) (radio transcript)
- ["...intervention plan for four at-risk youth."](http://repository.cityu.edu/handle/20.500.11803/234) (PhD dissertation)
- ["Matching of [four/two/an] at-risk youth..."](http://friendsforyouth.org/golf-sponsorships/) (organization website)
- ["...for eight homeless youth, ages 16-21"](http://www.yss.ames.ia.us/en/programs/homeless_youth_services/how_we_help/supportive_housing/) (organization website)
- ["One of the tech-savvy, ask-risk youth has a question"](http://slog.thestranger.com/slog/archives/2013/07/10/one-of-the-tech-savvy-ask-risk-youth-has-a-question-for-slog) (newspaper's blog)
- ["A special programme places 2,000 at-risk youth..."](http://www.economist.com/blogs/democracyinamerica/2015/07/summer-chicago) (The Economist)
- ["Troubled youths"](http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2015/08/daily-chart-7) (The Economist)
- ["...all homeless youth had beds."](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/28/nyregion/housing-homeless-youth-poses-challenge-for-mayor-de-blasio.html?action=click&contentCollection=N.Y.%20%2F%20Region&module=RelatedCoverage&region=EndOfArticle&pgtype=article) (NY Times)

I don't know the extent of this usage - it seems clear to me that it is accepted in American social services, and is perhaps especially common in the Pacific Northwest. I do think the usage is not limited to social service clients and professionals. For example, most every episode of the Savage Lovecast, one of the top 20 podcasts on iTunes, mentions production help from a group of "tech-savvy at-risk youth". At least one member of this group is female and the term is sometimes explicitly numerated as in the last link in my list above.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/youth) gives a definition of *youth* as

> (countable) A young person.

albeit without citation. The following definition is "A young man."

Comment: This answer does not, as far as I can see, address OP's question, which is about the count usage. (Or if the first sentence is meant to do so, it is a worry that 'In sociology/social work, _youth_ is a gender-neutral term' is  focusing too much on domain-specific usage where the domain overlaps enormously with the public domain. Are members of the public with whom the social services interact supposed to toe the in-house line rather than follow what their dictionaries say the most common usage is?)

Comment: I should clarify: In my experience *children* was still often used alone, but *children and youth* was encouraged by advocacy and service organizations representing or serving these youth---the youth felt excluded when *children* was used alone. So no, the social service professionals were not imposing an in-house rule on the public they serve; rather, they were responding to their public's request.

Comment: As far as count usage, *youth* is being treated as grammatically equivalent to *children* in these settings, thus countable.

Comment: As far as "*what their dictionaries say the most common usage is*" goes---this is my first day on this particular Stack Exchange, so perhaps I'm making a *faux pas*---but I assume dictionaries often lag well behind "the most common usage".

Comment: No; the test for the countness of a usage given by CGEL is not based on form but 'does it accept a numeral?' Thus 'ten children are' but not *'ten youth are'. 'We saw two lights shining in the distance' but not 'a subtle light suffused the glade' / *'seven subtle lights suffused the glade'. // Better dictionaries are updated quite regularly, with new usages and trends indicated (OED is perhaps slower than many here). There corpora are not domain-specific. Look up their websites for their policies, usage panels etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "***an*** at-risk youth" implies countability and in this example is genderless. 1 youth, 5 youths, 1 child, 5 children.

Comment: "An at-risk youth" is certainly a count usage; "six at-risk youths" is available. However, "three youths were seen loitering on the street corner" would be assumed to be an indication that they were males more often than not (as the dictionaries indicate: they sample for usage). Claiming that _youth_ when count is gender-neutral is incorrect, and using _youth_ when count in the belief that it is gender-neutral is naive at best.

Comment: Please see edits - I've removed the mentions of non-count usage and added several examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd also echo David Richerby's comment below - the context of "loitering on the street corner" suggests *male* perhaps more than the term "youth". Would your *male* expectation change (or change much) were it "three teenagers loitering on the street corner"?

Comment: The examples are a great improvement to the answer. This has to be taken seriously; however, so does the fact that the dictionaries (which sample in a professional way and across registers) state either that the count usage is restricted to males, or applies more often to males. This indicates that the count usage can _not_ be regarded as gender-neutral. Of course, institutions etc are free to use terminology as they deem fit, but they are duty-bound to define their usages if the default senses are overridden.

Answer (score 0):

In British English "youth" certainly has the implication of "male," and often also "badly behaved" and/or "poorly educated.". Hence the humorous (or derogatory) spelling "yoof" (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yoof)

As one-word alternatives, you could consider "juveniles," "adolescents, or "teenagers" instead of "youths". Those words are all gender-neutral.

Comment: Must be British English specific. Youth has pretty much lost gender connotation in American English.

Comment: I think "youth" only connotes "male" indirectly in British English. If we take it to mean "badly behaved and/or poorly educated young person", none of those individual terms suggests male. I would suggest that "youth" is just as gender-neutral as "train driver": the word is more commonly applied to males but doesn't directly imply maleness.

Comment: I'll agree with @DavidRicherby, but further it by saying that context matters. "Three youths attacked the old lady as she left the shop" - I would assume male. "Youths today drink less alcohol than their parents did in their younger days" - I would assume genderless.

Comment: @AndyT But it's the attacking that makes you assume male, not the use of the word "youth". In other words, if you're in a context that makes you assume male, you assume male -- that's all coming from the context.